# How to console.log my api data, outside of subscribe in angular

Tags: angular

here is my code :

```
public data: any;

constructor(private questionsService: QuestionsService) {

 this.questionsService.getAll().pipe(first()).subscribe(data => this.data = data);

 console.log(this.data);

}
```

How to console.log my api data, outside of subscribe in angular ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: why do you need this? what are you going to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` in `ngOnInit` and `await` `firstValueFrom()`.

```js
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.data = await firstValueFrom(this.questionsService.getAll());
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

But this is converting to Promises instead of using Observables as intended.